# Angular: How to get value from one component's frontend (app.compont.html) to another component's backend (other.component.ts)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

Consider a simple crud scenario. I have a lot of input fields and buttons in `app.component.html`. When i press a button from `app.component.html`, it will send html field value to 'other.component.ts' component and will display the result back in `app.component.html` after processing (like add, subtract or other).

Here is **app.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="posts/">Show Posts</a>
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="get-one-post-id">
<a routerLink="/post-by-id">Show One Posts</a>


<router-outlet>

</router-outlet>
```

**post-by-id-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-by-id',
  templateUrl: './post-by-id.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-by-id.component.css']
})
export class PostByIdComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: object;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // const id = ??
    this.GetPost(1);
  }

  async GetPost(id: number)
  {
    const response = await this.dataService.Get_A_Post(id);
    const dataService = await response.json();
    this.posts = dataService;
  }

}
```

**post-by-id-component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>
```

I just want to get value from the field called **get-one-post-id** from **app.component.html** to **post-by-id-component.ts** [where I commented // const id = ??]. But i can't find a way to import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share Data between Angular Components exists 4 different ways:

1. Parent to Child: Sharing Data via Input
2. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via ViewChild
3. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter
4. Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service

You can read [this](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) useful article to see how it works.